# Static linking of Glibc

Tags: c++, g++, glibc, static-linking

How can i compile my app linking statically glibc library, but only the code needed for my app? (Not all lib)

Now my compile command:

```
g++  -o newserver  test.cpp ... -lboost_system -lboost_thread -std=c++0x
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That's what `-static` does (as described in another answer): unneeded modules won't get linked into your program. But your expectations on the amount of stuff which is *needed* (in a sense that we can't convince linker to the contrary) may be too optimistic.

If you trying to do it for portability (running an executable on other machines with older glibc or something like that), there is one easy test question to see if you're going to get what you want:

Did you think of the problem with `libnss`, and are you sure it is not going to bite you?

If your answer is *yes*, maybe it makes sense to go on. If the answer is no, or the question seems too obscure and there is no answer, just quit your expirements with statically linked glibc: it has more chance to hurt than help.

Answer (score 4):

Add `-static` to the compile line. It will only add what your application needs [and of course, any functions the functions you application calls, and any functions those functions call, including a bunch of startup code and some other bits and pieces], so it will be around 800K (for a simple "hello world" program) on an x86 machine. Other architectures vary. Since boost probably also calls the standard library at least a little bit, it's likely that you will have more than 800K added to your appliciation. But it only applies functions used by any of the code in the final binary, not the entire library [about 2MB as a shared library].

If you ONLY want link glibc, you will need to modify the linking line to your compile to:
`-Wl,-Bstatic -libc -Wl,-Bdynamic`. This will prevent any other library from being linked statically [you sometimes need to have more than one of these statements, as sometimes something pulled in by another library requires "more" from glibc to be pulled in - don't worry, it won't bring in anything more than the linker thinks is necessary].

Comment: That will also link statically to the boost libs, and other libs, which I don't think is wanted (but I'm not sure I understand the question)

Comment: Ah, good point, You have to trick about a bit to only link ONE library statically.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, i need this because on client machines may be 2.5, 2.2 version of glibc, but i have 2.7 version and i need to do my app work on all versions of glibc (or one-two last versions), how can i compile to achieve this?Thanks!